# Is it possible to store a C data type in a variable?

Tags: c, types

**Is it possible to store a C data type in a variable?**

Something like this:

```c
void* type = (byte*);
```

---

Here is a scenario, where I wrote a test case and tried to print out a byte array using certain data types for use in printf, depending on the given parameters:

```c
void print_byteArray(const void* expected, size_t size, 
        bool asChars, bool asWCharT) {
    int iterations;
    char* format;
    if (asChars) {
        iterations = (size / (sizeof (char)));
        format = "%c";
    } else if (asWCharT) {
        iterations = (size / (sizeof (wchar_t)));
        format = "%lc";
    } else {
        iterations = (size / (sizeof (byte)));
        format = "%x";
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        if (asChars) {
            printf(format, ((char*) expected)[i]);
        } else if (asWCharT) {
            printf(format, ((wchar_t*) expected)[i]);
        } else {
            printf(format, ((byte*) expected)[i]);
        }
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

This looks like inefficient code. I'd imagine it that one could size-down the for-loop body to a single line:

```c
printf(format, ((type) expected)[i]);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there's no such type that can store a type in standard C.

gcc provides a `typeof` extension that may be useful. The syntax of using of this keyword looks like `sizeof`, but the construct acts semantically like a type name defined with `typedef`. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) for detail.

Some more examples of the use of `typeof`:

This declares y with the type of what x points to.

```
typeof (*x) y;
```

This declares y as an array of such values.

```
typeof (*x) y[4];
```

This declares y as an array of pointers to characters:

```
typeof (typeof (char *)[4]) y;
```

It is equivalent to the following traditional C declaration:

```
char *y[4];
```

To see the meaning of the declaration using typeof, and why it might be a useful way to write, rewrite it with these macros:

```
#define pointer(T)  typeof(T *)
#define array(T, N) typeof(T [N])
```

Now the declaration can be rewritten this way:

```
array (pointer (char), 4) y;
```

Thus, `array (pointer (char), 4)` is the type of arrays of 4 pointers to char.

Comment: Is there a way to define and use `typeof` outside of gcc?

Answer (score 0):

C is a statically-typed language, so you would have to build your own run-time type system. However, if one just wants to print values of arbitrary data, one can use `printf`'s `%s` and work with temporary string buffers. This will work in some cases where the data you want to print is bounded:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_ */
#include <stdio.h>  /* *printf */

#define PRINT_BUFFERS (4)

struct Foo {
    int key;
    char value[32];
};

/** Assumes {key} is {[0, 99]} to comply with C90, otherwise use {snprintf}. */
static void Foo_to_string(const struct Foo *foo, char (*const a)[12]) {
    sprintf(*a, "%d%.9s", foo->key, foo->value);
}
/** This is more convenient, but lacks generality. */
static const char *Foo_to_static(const struct Foo *foo) {
    static char buffers[PRINT_BUFFERS][12];
    static unsigned n;
    char *const a = buffers[n];
    sprintf(a, "%d%.9s", foo->key, foo->value);
    n = (n + 1) % PRINT_BUFFERS;
    return a;
}

int main(void) {
    const struct Foo foo = { 42, "foo" }, bar = { 96, "bar" },
        baz = { 13, "baz_abcdefg" };
    /* This way is more general. */
    char a[12], b[12], c[12];
    Foo_to_string(&foo, &a);
    Foo_to_string(&bar, &b);
    Foo_to_string(&baz, &c);
    printf ("Foo: %s; Bar: %s; Baz: %s.\n", a, b, c);
    /* This way is convenient, but you have a max number of calls. */
    printf("Foo: %s; Bar: %s; Baz: %s.\n", Foo_to_static(&foo),
        Foo_to_static(&bar), Foo_to_static(&baz));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```